# get core data latest -id and give -(+1) for new insert

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, int

I have coredata `user` table and have inside

### user

id (int32)
name (string)

I want to look firstly latest id and I want to do `let newid = latestid(from user table) - (-1)` for example;

### My user table have

id = 0 name = Mary
id = -1 name = john

I want new insert id must be **-2**

> How can I do it ?

My codes under below.

```
 let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "user")
        let sortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "id", ascending: true)
        fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [sortDescriptor]

        var newid = Int32()

        do {
            let result = try context.fetch(fetchRequest).last as! user!
            if result != nil {
                if Int((result?.id)!) < 0 {
                    let lw = Int((result?.id)!)
                    newid = Int32(Int(lw - (1)))
                }else{
                    newid = Int32(Int((result?.id)!) - 1)
                }
            }
        } catch let error as NSError {
            NSLog("Error \(error)")
        }


        let Add = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObject(forEntityName: "user", into:context) as! user
        Add.id = Int32(newid)
        Add.name = name.text
            (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).saveContext()

     print(newid)
```

When I try that codes , first time doing id = 0 true, after I try again gives id -1 true , but when I try more more gives id -1 all of them. must be -2,-3,-4,-5 etc..

Comment: Currently you sort in ascending order: -1 comes before 0, so the last item in the array is always the object with id = 0.  So all new objects get id = -1.  Either change the sort descriptor to `ascending:false`, or set result to `context.fetch(fetchRequest).first`.

Comment: What is your goal with these ids?  If you want to sort by showing the mostly recently created I think you would be better served by having a value of creationDate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Finally I found solition**

use `ascending: false`  and change only

```
if result != nil {
                if Int((result?.id)!) < 0 {
                    newid = Int((result?.id)!)
                }else{
                    newid = 0
                }
  newid = Int((result?.id)!) - (+1)
```